# How can I force Composer to install a dev branch over a stable release?

Tags: composer

I am experimenting with Bootstrap 3 in Drupal 8 and I want to stay on the dev branch of bootstrap.

In my `composer.json`, I wrote the following line based on [Drupal Packagist](https://packagist.drupal-composer.org/packages/drupal/bootstrap):

```
"drupal/bootstrap": "8.3.*@dev",
```

However, when I run `composer update`, it downloads `8.3.0-beta2` (2015-Dec-19) instead of the latest dev release (2016-Feb-20).

```
Gathering patches for root package.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Gathering patches for root package.
Gathering patches for dependencies. This might take a minute.
  - Installing drupal/bootstrap (8.3.0-beta2)
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%
```

To make sure it wasn't some caching issue, I ran:

```
composer selfupdate
composer clear-cache
composer update
```

But it did the same thing-- install beta2.

How do I force it to download the dev release instead?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While it will install the latest dev release of the Drupal module/theme to simply do the following:

```
composer require drupal/bootstrap:3.x-dev
```

I would argue a **best practice** when installing a dev version of a module is to make sure you are going to get the commit you want (which might not be the latest), so I would do the following:

```
composer require drupal/bootstrap:3.x-dev#5670922dea05fffb6506a6cd5d53546b9fae8df9
```

Or you can manually add it to your require in composer.json (as below) and then on the command line run `composer install`

```
"drupal/bootstrap": "3.x-dev#5670922dea05fffb6506a6cd5d53546b9fae8df9",
```

To get the commit you should go to http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bootstrap/log/ and find the commit you want (the commit hash is the id on the commit's page).
btw: the above hash is not a real commit on the Bootstrap project

Answer (score 16):

You can keep the original prefer-stable settings. The `@dev` in `8.3.*@dev` is the stability flag for the given package. The easiest way to force a dev-version of a package is to use a different version constraint. Use `8.3.x-dev` instead, this version constraint references to a the `8.x-3.x` branch and works independently from `prefer-stable` and `minimum-stability`.

Comment: A composer require command that goes with this would look something like this `composer require "drupal/page_manager:1.x-dev"`

Comment: @daniels – You don't need the quotes.

Comment: So the `-dev` of the branch is like `@dev`? Is there a rule for that like git branch + suffix? I've seen it as a prefix or suffix (interchangeably) but I don't see a rule `dev-4.x` or `4.x-dev` or `4.x@dev` all of the above?