# How to install a specifc commit in Composer

Tags: 8, webforms, composer, version-control

The commerce_webform_order module (currently in dev status) recently [changed one of its dependencies](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_webform_order/-/commit/a5eba6d6d7bfa45da336c778e8a3db78505905db) from Webform 5.x (stable) to Webform 6.x (alpha). I want to temporarily freeze commerce_webform_module so that Composer keeps it at a particular git commit just before the dependencies changed. I've done this successfully in the past by following a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784809/how-to-use-a-specific-tag-version-with-composer-and-a-private-git-repository) but I can't get it to work this time.

I've tried doing 
`composer require drupal/commerce_webform_order:1.x-dev#30668342035ae3add3a2e5163e84816fc96edd92`
or adding
 `"drupal/commerce_webform_order "1.x-dev#30668342035ae3add3a2e5163e84816fc96edd92",` in my `composer.json` file and I've tried shorter versions of the commit hash (30668342) as shown on [the drupalcode.org project here](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_webform_order/-/commit/30668342035ae3add3a2e5163e84816fc96edd92).

I keep getting this message

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
- Can only install one of: drupal/webform[6.x-dev, 5.19.0].
- drupal/commerce_webform_order 1.x-dev requires drupal/webform ^6 -> satisfiable by drupal/webform[6.x-dev].
- Installation request for drupal/commerce_webform_order 1.x-dev#30668342035ae3add3a2e5163e84816fc96edd92 -> satisfiable by drupal/commerce_webform_order[1.x-dev].
```

What might be causing this? What's changed in the last 6 months since it worked for me on the same module last time?

Can you think of any other work-around that allows me to update everything else without pulling in this latest change and the dependency for an alpha version of Webform?

Thanks

Comment: One workaround appears to be to “fake” the package version, by aliassing it, see https://ma.ttias.be/composer-require-specific-version-while-ignoring-dependencies/. So maybe try this for Webform. In your require section have `"drupal/webform": "^5.9 as 6.0"`. This approach is also been described here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-higher

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right version?  The code you're using looks alright if the version is correct; see this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/245492/5147

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
composer require drupal/commerce_webform_order:dev-1.x#30668342035ae3add3a2e5163e84816fc96edd92
```

dev-1.x points to a git branch so it accepts the commit ref

1.x-dev is dev release at drupal.org and it does not have git commits to reference like that